# How to prevent an Android app from embedding my website

Tags: javascript, java, android, frontend, embed

I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent developers from embedding my website in their Android apps. I've tried user agent sniffing, but I ran into a problem where I'd accidentally prevent Android users on their mobile browsers from viewing my sites. Any way to detect if the site has been embedded, either through JavaScript or another tool?

Comment: Do you want to prevent embeds everywhere, or just on Android?

Comment: Pretty much impossible-  anything you think up, they can get around.  Except for actual authentication required to view it, of course.  That's the nature of the web-  if you put material on it for free download (which is what html and javascript on a web server is), you can't really stop anyone from using it anyway they want.

Comment: @TheWanderer just on Android, I don't want my site getting wrapped and served in Android apps.

Comment: I know Google detects Android WebViews somehow, but it's easily spoofed by just setting the WebView's useragent to something else.

Comment: Chrome is an Android app. Firefox is an Android app. Plenty of other browsers are Android apps. You need to explain, in precise technical terms, what distinguishes an Android app that you like from an Android app that you do not like.